# WCF Object Serialization

Tags: wcf

Im having problem in serializing object.

Here's my sample code:

Service Code:

```
///////////////////////
  // REQUEST INTERFACE //
  ///////////////////////
  SystemResponse IRequest.ChangeStatus(Models.RequestParameters pParameters)
  {
   SystemResponse response = new SystemResponse();
   response = new Models.Request().ChangeStatus(pParameters);
   return response;
  }

  Models.RequestModel IRequest.Fill(int pRequestCode)
  {
   return new Models.Request().Fill(pRequestCode);
  }

  List<Models.RequestModel> IRequest.GetList(string pUserID)
  {
   return new Models.Request().GetList(pUserID);
  }
```

Models.RequestModel

```
 [DataContract]
 public class RequestModel
 {
  [DataMember]
  public int RequestCode { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Actions Action { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string AffectedTable { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> WhereValues { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> NewValues { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> OldValues { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Remarks { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public Status RequestStatus { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string CheckedBy { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime? CheckedOn { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime? ApprovedOn { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<RequestChildModel> RequestChilds { get; set; }
 }

 public enum Actions
 {
  DELETE = 0,
  UPDATE = 1,
  INSERT = 2
 }

 public enum Status
 { 
  NA = -1,
  PENDING = 0,
  CHECKED = 1,
  APPROVED = 2,
  REJECTED = 3,
  CANCELLED = 4
 }

 [DataContract]
 public struct Values
 {
  [DataMember]
  public string FieldName { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public object Value { get; set; }
 }
```

Models.RequestChild

```
[DataContract] 
 public class RequestChildModel
 {
  [DataMember]
  public int RequestChildCode { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int RequestCode { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string AffectedTable { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> WhereValues { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> NewValues { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<Values> OldValues { get; set; }
 }
```

When Serializing the Models.RequestModel. When i remove the following code

```
  Models.RequestModel IRequest.Fill(int pRequestCode)
  {
   return new Models.Request().Fill(pRequestCode);
  }

  List<Models.RequestModel> IRequest.GetList(string pUserID)
  {
   return new Models.Request().GetList(pUserID);
  }
```

the Service will work perfectly if i remove the two function. But when I add the two methods, i got this error message

[image]

Please help. I need to get the GetList and Fill function work.
GetList will return all request details and Fill will return request details.

Comment: You can turn on WCF Tracing in order to see which property is causing the problem and you don't need to guess.

Comment: You could copy the entire error message, the print screen you used does not have all relevant information about the error.
As you're using `DataContract`, you should also use `EnumMember` in enums (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa347875(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, just to clarify, why did you choose a `struct` instead of a `class` or a `Dictionary` ?